# What does DB: Warning: execution completed with warning (SQL State: 99999 - Error Code: 17110) mean?

Tags: oracle, flyway

I am creating partitions like this:

```
ALTER TABLE ${whatever.test.owner}.MY_TABLE MODIFY
        PARTITION BY RANGE(CREATION_TMSTMP) INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'day'))
    ( partition p_first values less than (to_date('2016-06-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')));

ALTER TABLE ${whatever.test.owner}.MY_TABLE ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;
```

I get this warning "DB: Warning: execution completed with warning (SQL State: 99999 - Error Code: 17110)" on some tables. On most tables the script runs fine I get it only for a few tables. The script seems to work it looks like there are no problems even if I get a warning. I tried to google it and I did not find anything that would explain my problem.

This is how I run the script:

```
./gradlew flywayClean -Dflyway.configFiles=../path -i

./gradlew flywayMigrate -Dflyway.configFiles=../path -i
```

Comment: @APC I use Flyway.

Comment: @APC: I have seen that error message "*execution completed with warning (SQL State: 99999 - Error Code: 17110)*" with "plain" DDL statements in Oracle before, so I assume this is not directly related to Flyway. Unfortunately, I never found the root cause though.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I think that's JDBC reporting a SQL error. What I meant was, it wasn't an error thrown by (say) SQL*Plus.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I can not understand it as well. What is strange is that everything works fine.

Comment: Maybe [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48118045/146325) from Axel Fontaine (author of Flyway) can help?